# Rails - DB migration best practice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, database-migration, rails-migrations

I have designed the following migration and wanted to check with the community is that is meeting the best practices of rails migration.  I am running a postgres db.

I am trying to achieve a db structure where the various status attached to a user is stored in a separate table.  for instance, its marital status.

let me know if that sounds like a reasonably efficient table design.  and what I could improve.

```
class CreatePrequalifications < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
 def change
   create_table :prequalifications do |t|
    t.string :attachment
    t.text :description
    t.integer :marital_status
    t.integer :professional_status
    t.integer :collateral_status
    t.integer :income_direct
    t.integer :income_support
    t.integer :income_scolarship
    t.integer :income_other
    t.boolean :blacklist

    t.references :user, foreign_key: true

    t.timestamps
  end
end

create_table :marital_status do |t|
  t.string :single
  t.string :married
  t.string :other
  t.string :divorced
  t.string :with_dependants
  t.references :user, foreign_key: true
  t.references :prequalifications, foreign_key: true
end

create_table :professional_status do |t|
  t.string :self_employed
  t.string :employed
  t.string :student
  t.string :other
  t.text :description
  t.datetime :contract_created_at
  t.datetime :contract_terminated_at

  t.references :user, foreign_key: true
  t.references :prequalifications, foreign_key: true
end

create_table :collateral_status do |t|
  t.string :collateral_name

  t.string :collateral_income
  t.boolean :visale_collateral
  t.boolean :student_collateral
  t.boolean :bank_collateral

  t.references :user, foreign_key: true
  t.references :prequalifications, foreign_key: true
end
```

end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, best practices would dictate:

1. Break each `create_table` into its own migration.
2. Your table names should be pluralized, e.g. `marital_statuses`.
3. Time stamps are a good idea.
4. Consider adding indexes to fields that will be queried regularly, e.g. model names, user emails, or foreign keys.

Check out the rails guide on migrations for information about best practice: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with:

1. Is it a single migration? If so, I would start with splitting it into several migrations (one for each table).
2. Add timestamps for each table (`t.timestamps null: false`). You will thank me later ;)
3. For statuses tables (`martial_status`, `professional_status`) create simpler tables with just name and references (no need to create column for each value). Also, you probably do not need the table for marital status, because you can use [classy_enum](https://github.com/beerlington/classy_enum) instead.
4. In `prequalifications` you have integer columns for relations (`maritial_status`, `professional_status`). Don't do that, use `references`.
5. For boolean columns, define default values.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  I run that as multiple models. I note that timestamps null:false is added by rails (im running (5.2.2) so I did nothing but checked that was there.